# If a positive term series is less or equal to a positive real number for any finite n, will $S_n$ still bound by the same number for $n \to +\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For example, if $S_n = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n a_k$ $\leqslant$ $R$ for any **finite** positive integer $n$ where $R$ is a fixed real number, will $Sn$ still bound by $R$ for $n \to +\infty$? if so, how to prove it? Or if it is not true, what is the counterexample?

Initially, I thought bounded monotone convergence theorem could help prove the yes. However, it seems that bounded monotone convergence theorem merely works for bounded sequence where bounded means |$S_n$| should be bounded for any $n$ instead of finite $n$.

Comment: Yes. $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an increasing and bounded sequence, and hence it converges to $\sup[(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty]\leq R$. This is the monotone convergence theorem. Unless I'm misunderstanding some detail in the question.

Comment: @Eff: $S_k$ is bounded by $R$ for finite $n$, I'm not sure whether it will be still bounded by the $R$ for $n->\infty$.

Comment: When we say that $n\to\infty$ we always have that $n$ is finite. We simply look at the behaviour as $n$ increases (without bound), we never have that $n$ "is equal" to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{S_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence of positive real numbers, and also bounded above by $R$ since $S_n \leq R, \forall n \geq 1$, hence it is converging to a finite real number $L$.

**Claim**: $L \leq R$

For if otherwise $L >R$, then let $\epsilon = L-R > 0$, then $\exists N \geq 1: |S_n-L| < L-R\Rightarrow L-S_n < L-R\Rightarrow R < S_n, n \geq N$, contradiction. Thus: $L \leq R$.

Comment: Awesome, I'm impressed by your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very basic theorem of limits. If $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$ for all values of $n$ after a certain point then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$ provided both the limits exist. In the current question $b_{n} = R$ is a constant sequence and we have $a_{n} = S_{n}$ and hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_{n} \leq R$. Also note that even if we have $a_{n} < b_{n}$ then also the conclusion is $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n}$. Thus *taking limits always weakens the inequalities*.

A proof of this basic theorem on limits in easy. Suppose $A = \lim a_{n}, B = \lim b_{n}$ and assume on the contrary that $A > B$. Intuitively we can bring $a_{n}$ so close to $A$ that it exceeds $B$ and remains closer to $A$ than to $B$. Similarly we can bring $b_{n}$ so close to $B$ so that it is less than $A$ and remains closer to $B$ than to $A$. Thus after a certain point $a_{n} > b_{n}$ contrary to our hypothesis.

The above informal argument can be made formal (*not rigorous because the argument of previous paragraph is already fully rigorous*) by use of nasty $\epsilon$. Again suppose $A > B$ and let $\epsilon = (A - B)/2 > 0$. Then we have a positive integer $n_{1}$ such that $$|a_{n} - A| < \epsilon$$ for $n > n_{1}$. Thus $$A - \epsilon < a_{n} < A + \epsilon$$ for $n > n_{1}$. Similarly $$B - \epsilon < b_{n} < B + \epsilon$$ for $n > n_{2}$. if $n_{0} = \max(n_{1}, n_{2})$ then we have for $n > n_{0}$ the following inequality $$B - \epsilon < b_{n} < B + \epsilon = A - \epsilon < a_{n} < A + \epsilon$$ and thus $a_{n} > b_{n}$ for all $n > n_{0}$. Thus we achieve a contradiction and therefore $A \leq B$.

Comment: appreciate your answer^_^

Comment: @Bearandbunny: thanks for the appreciation. You may upvote my answer (as well as upvote the accepted answer by KfScOc)